# Change message contents with AppeScript

Tags: event-handling, applescript, macos-sierra

I was recently messing around with the AppleScripts aspect of the Messages app on macOS Sierra and found the `Mixed Message Case.applescript` file, and changed the the appropriate handler in the Messages preferences.

Nothing seemed to happen when it should have (on a message received, change the text to mixed case, e.g. "hello" -> "HeLlO"). I checked the functionality of the script with some `display dialog` debug statements and it seems fine, though the message contents aren't being changed.

This begs the question: how does one change incoming or outgoing messages with AppleScript?